# How to combine rows of list of string based on another column's value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

```
|Name |Txt              |
| --- |-----------------|
|Mike |[I like pie]     |
|Jason| [Good morning] |
|Mike | [good afternoon]|
|Jason| [One two three]|
```

I want to turn it into something like this:

```
|Name |Txt                        |
| --- | ------------------------- |
|Mike |I like pie Good morning    |
|Jason| Good morning One two three|
```

The Txt column should be ready for word tokenize. Btw, the original data has more than 50k rows...

I have tried to use `groupby.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x["Txt"]))`, but somehow it is not working properly.

I also tried to use `str.cat(sep=" ")`, but I was only able to merge all of them into one big file.

Hope someone can help me fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `str.cat()`

```
df.groupby('Name')['Text'].apply(lambda x:x.str.cat(sep=" "))
```